# postback cause signalR diconnect (v2)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

So I created a site master page holding the online users list 
but now everytime i navigate to another page or refresh the page, its refreshing the all list to all clients connected..
it's really annoying, how can I avoid that?

```
  public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        if (stopCalled)
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var currentUser = manager.FindByName(Context.User.Identity.Name);
            string name = currentUser.NickName;

            userNames.Remove(name);


            Clients.All.hubReceived(userNames);
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```

that's my disconnect action

and here's the client side:

```
     <script>
         $(function () {
             // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
             var hub = $.connection.chatHub;
             // Update player list
             hub.client.hubReceived = function (usernames) {
                 $('#onlineUsersList').text("");
                 console.log(usernames.length)
                 if (usernames.length > 0) {
                     for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
                         if (usernames[i] != "")
                             $("#onlineUsersList").append("<div class='userli'> <img src='Content/Images/profilepic.jpg' style='width: 32px; height: 32px;'/><span>" + usernames[i] + "</span></div>")
                         //  $('#usersList').append(usernames[i]);
                     }
                 }
             };
             hub.client.test = function (x) {
                 alert(x);
             };

             $.connection.hub.start();
         });



</script>
```

Comment: "it's really annoying, how can I avoid that?" just don't navigate back from the page or don't do a postback, because this is a complete page reload. The same thing as when you close the browser and open the page in a new browser. Maybe SignalR is the wrong thing here or you should avoid moving back from the current page.

Comment: SignalR client stops the connection in the `unload`/`beforeunload` event. You could probably unbind the handler but then you will have a bunch of dangling connections which would eventually time out. Once you reload/close/navigate you have no way of using the existing connection because you don't have a reference.